# Coordinate Transforms for Google Street View like UI

Tags: 3d, coordinate-systems

[Google Street View](https://www.google.com/streetview/) allows you to explore a 3D space using mouse drag. You essentially drag your mouse across the screen and the UI changes the orientation of a virtual scene camera.

Assume you have a function $f$ that converts a mouse drag represented by the start pixel position $(x_1, y_1)$ & end pixel position $(x_2, y_2)$ of a mouse drag into a 3D rotation ([Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles)) for the virtual scene camera.

$f: R^4 \to R^3$

Now a few questions about $f$.

1. What are the possible ways to define $f$?
2. With the definition chosen in *1*, is $f$ a continuous function?
3. With the definition chosen in *1*, is $f$ a surjective function?
4. With the definition chosen in *1*, is $f$ an injective function?

Comment: I think it's more like $\mathbb [a,b]\times [c,d] \to S^2$.  The camera is at the origin, your $x$ and $y$ movements become rotations of a half-cone (field of view) on the interior of the spherical shell. While a continuous function may model this, it is of a series of small but discrete steps.

Comment: @DavidP Updated the question with the correct domain and codomain for $f$